# Teamcity job reports duplicated karma-jasmine-webpack tests count

Tags: teamcity, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

Running karma with webpack and jasmine i am getting team city to report 300 tests instead of 150.

These are jasmine tests for angular client side.

Any idea why?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check that TeamCity's "XML Report Processing" build feature is disabled.